# Select multiple rows with matching id(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried for hours and read many posts but I still can't figure out how to handle this request:

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
|roleid|comid |
+------+------+
|11    | A    |
+------+------+
|12    | A    |
+------+------+
|11    |B     |
+------+------+
|12    |B     |
+------+------+
|13    |B     |
+------+------+
```

I would like to select the roleid that occurs more than once with the different comid.

I wanna output should be something like:

```
+------+------+
|roleid|comid |
+------+------+
|11    |A,B   |
+------+------+
|12    |A,B   |
+------+------+
|13    |B     |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can use `STUFF()` function with `FOR XML PATH('')` as

```
SELECT roleid,
       STUFF(
         (
           SELECT ',' + comid
           FROM T
           WHERE roleid = T1.roleid
           FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''
       ) comid 
FROM T T1
GROUP BY roleid
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb210ea37ea7ecedf0b243863e677de1)**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server version greater than or equal to 2017, you can use also `STRING_AGG` function and to take only those `roleid`s having more than one distinct `comid` you have to use `HAVING` caluse:

```
SELECT roleid,
       STRING_AGG(comid, ',')
FROM T
GROUP BY roleid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT comid) > 1
```

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2017 but the error is occur i.e. 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.